Type A is not assignable to type B in ternary operator
I have a piece of code that triggers the title issue but not the other, they do the same thing and have no clue why.
the one who triggers the TS2345 (I tried to type and not typing data here, same result)
const data : Element[]|null = usePewFetcher(
    projectId ? 
      pewFetcher.projectApplicationsFromProject({id: projectId}):
      pewFetcher.applications({})
    , []
  )

the one okay
  let data;
  if( projectId ) {
    data = usePewFetcher(
      pewFetcher.projectApplicationsFromProject({id: projectId}) //return type : ApplicationProject[] (extending Element)
      , []
    )
  } else {
    data = usePewFetcher(
      pewFetcher.applications({}) //return type : Application[] (extending Element)
      , []
    )
  }

export function usePewFetcher<T>(pewFetcher: Promise<T>, deps?: any[]): T|null {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const call = async () => {
      setData(await pewFetcher as any)
    }
    call()
  }, deps)
  return data;
}

Application and ApplicationProject are both inherited from Element but they have different properties

With your first approach using the ternary operator, you are trying to infer the generic type by passing two different arguments.
The TypeScript compiler seems to take the first type (ApplicationProject[]) as the generic type and tries to apply the second one (Application[]) - it does not work as the compiler does not work out their respective common base.
You can explicitly pass those two types to the usePewFetcher to work around this
const data: Element[] | null = usePewFetcher<ApplicationProject[] | Application[]>(
    projectId ?
        pewFetcher.projectApplicationsFromProject({ id: projectId }) :
        pewFetcher.applications({})
    , [],
);

or pass the common base interface
const data: Element[] | null = usePewFetcher<Element[]>(
    projectId ?
        pewFetcher.projectApplicationsFromProject({ id: projectId }) :
        pewFetcher.applications({})
    , [],
);

